# A device on my home network won't pick up router SSID

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

I'm new to networking and I've come across a problem on my home network. I can connect to my router via every device on the network apart from two devices such as an HP laptop running windows 10 and an Android box, both for some reason will not pickup the SSID of the router.

I did a bit of research and found people suggesting checking the 2.5/5Ghz setting in my router settings but I found that my router now forces 5Ghz after an update which I'm assuming was by my ISP. Not sure if this is the problem but just going off of suggestions from some googling.

If anyone has any potential solutions I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 2.4GHz radio was disabled by your ISP, and you have older devices that only support 2.4GHz, then:

- Call your ISP, complain, and replace the router.
- Log into the router and see if you can revert settings.  If your ISP can overwrite settings you are better off with the next thing below:
- Replace your ISPs modem router with one of your own and purchase your own dual-band router.
- For the laptop, you can buy a USB Wifi card that supports 5Ghz.
- For the Android box, you may need to stop using it, use a wired connection to your router if supported, or upgrade the device.
- You also can buy an older Wifi access point that supports 2.4GHz, configure it to work only as an AP (no DHCP, etc.), connect it to a switch port in your modem/router, and connect older wireless devices to this second AP.